# Difference between list<Observer*>* and list<Observer*> in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, design-patterns

EDIT: The question has been answered, thank you! Also, this code is part of the **Observer pattern**. If you know the pattern, you will understand this code. Thanks :)

I am learning the Observer pattern and I don't understand the extra * in code provided. 
The Subject.h has this code

```
//Subject.h
#pragma once
#include<list>
#include "Observable.h"

using namespace std;

class Subject : public Observable {

public:
    Subject();
    ~Subject();

    void attach(Observer *);
    void detach(Observer *);
    void notify();
private:
    list<Observer*>* _observers; // ----------Here there is two *
};
```

And the Obervable.h has this code (implementing the Observer.h...)

```
//Observable.h
#pragma once
#include <list>
using namespace std;

class Observer;

class Observable
{
public:
    virtual ~Observable() {};
    virtual void attach(Observer *) = 0;
    virtual void detach(Observer *) = 0;
    virtual void notify() = 0;
protected:
    Observable() {};
private:
    list<Observer*> _observers; // ----------Here there is only one *
};
```

Comment: It is the same as the difference between `int` and `int*`.

Comment: So in this case, it's a list of pointers to pointers?

Comment: No, it a pointer to a list of pointers to Observer.

Comment: @Mrtnchps `list<Observer**>`  would be a list of pointers to pointers

Comment: [OT] This seems like an odd design.

Comment: To make @Barry's point more strongly: the posted code is nonsense. Wherever that comes from, put it back and don't ever go there again.

Comment: @PeteBecker I didn't post all the code for the Observer pattern. I agree it can look confusing but if you know the pattern, you would understand the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**list** is one of the many classes provided by the Standard Library.

It behaves like any other class type:

```
int               : integer 
int*              : pointer to integer
Observer          : Observer instance
Observer*         : pointer to Observer instance
list<Observer>    : list of Observers
list<Observer*>*  : pointer to list of pointers to Observers
```